# Rename file name in GCP Cloud Storage and remove square brackets []

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We have many videos uploaded to GCP Cloud Storage.
We need to change file name and remove [].

Asking if there is a good solution.

file example:
gs://xxxxxx/xxxxxx/[BlueLobster] Saint Seiya The Lost Canvas - 06 [1080p].mkv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the given scenario, you want to bulk rename all the filenames with ¨[]¨. Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#objectnames), gsutil interprets these characters as wildcards. [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) does not support this currently.

There´s a way to handle this kind of request by using a custom script to rename all the files with ´[´.

You may use any programming languages that have [Cloud Storage client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries). For this instructions, we´ll be using **Python** for the custom script.

1. On your [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), Click the Activate Cloud Shell on the top right of the Google Cloud Console beside the question mark sign. For more information, you may refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell).
2. On your Cloud Shell, Install the Python client library by using this command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

For more information, please refer on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

4. After the installation of client library, launch the **Cloud Shell Editor** by clicking the **Open Editor** on the top right side of the Cloud Shell. You may refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell-editor) for more information.
5. On your **Cloud Shell Editor**, click the **File** menu and choose **New File**. Name it **script.py**. Click **Ok**.
6. This code assumes that all the objects on your bucket have the same name from the sample you provided.:

```
import re
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket_name = "my_bucket"
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

storage_client = storage.Client()

blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
pattern = r"[\([{})\]]"
for blob in blobs:
    out_var = blob.name
    fixed_var = re.sub(pattern, '', blob.name)
    print(out_var + " " + fixed_var)
    new_blob = bucket.rename_blob(blob, fixed_var)
```

1. Change the content of ¨**my_bucket**¨ to the name of your bucket.
2. Click **File** and then **Save** or you can just press **Ctrl + S**.
3. Go back to the terminal by clicking the **Open Terminal** on the top right section of the Cloud Shell Editor.
4. Copy and paste this code to the editor:

```
python script.py
```

5. To run the script, press the **Enter** key.
6. Files that have brackets are now renamed.

The files aren´t renamed in the backend. Under the hood, it's more of being rewritten with a new name and it's due to [object immutability](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability).  This will only copy the old files with a new name and removes the old file afterwards.

Comment: I repeat my warning, the file aren't renamed, they are copied with the new name and the old ones deleted. It can take time (2 API call + processing duration), and cost (a little) Operation B type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename file in Cloud Storage. Renaming file equals to copying the file with a new name and to delete the older name.

It will take time if you have a lot of (large) files, but it's not impossible.